# PDO fetching large amount of data

Tags: php, performance, postgresql, pdo, cursor

I'm trying to fetch large amount of data from PDO PostgreSQL database to compute them through a simplification algorithm (reducing number of rows) in php.

The problem is I can't use the fetchAll, having often a message:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted...

I then opted for a fetch using cursors which allows me to access wanted data whithout memory cares, like this example:

```
function simplify(&q){
    //Doing some stuff loop
     $current = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS, $index+1); //Iterators starts from 1
    //Doing some more stuff

}

[...]

$query = $this->connexion->prepare($req, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL)); //More than 100k results

$result = simplify($query);
```

Now, this works like a charm... except for the execution time which takes up to 1min to compute 200k rows.

I specify my algorithm use the recursive behavior which not help in my case.

Is there another solution to reduce execution time whithout eating too much memory?

I thinked about trigger on the DB server side, but what do you think?

Comment: Are you using all the facilities of SQL?

Comment: I've not totally the control on the database server, but I was thinking using ST_Simplify from the postgis plugin alternatively.